# How do i compare submitted string to encoded variable

Tags: javascript, variables, encode

Some years ago, in an effort to learn JS, I built an assignment/testing system for my engineering technology students (http://qwizm.org, any alphabetical username and integral ID gets you in). Now, to take advantage of my (slightly) increased knowledge, and 'new' technology such as local storage, it's time for a rewrite.

Everything is handled in the client. Students get reproducible 'unique' inputs to questions, based on their ID. Thus, each question or question part has a 'unique' answer. Correct answers, calculated and stored in variables at log in, are readily viewable using various browser developer tools. I would like to change this.

I've considered encoding the correct answer, then passing student form submissions through parseFloat and then encoding the numerical value corresponding to the input string. Comparing the two encoded values could then be used to decide whether or not the student entry is correct.

Students get unlimited penalty-free attempts so lazy evaluation of the correct answer doesn't solve the issue.

Can anyone see flaws in this, or suggest a better approach?

Comment: Validate if an answer is correct/wrong using a server side technology. Maintain a JSON type datastructure with questions and answers in server side program.

Comment: If you send the answers to the client, it can be viewed from developer options as you have indicated. Another approach is to send the answer to the back-end server and validate it. This will avoid encoding the answers submitted in the client.

Comment: I want to keep this completely client side after the page is downloaded. This way, instructors with no server access or skills can simply load the page into an LMS (as long as the LMS doesn't break anything) or distribute the html file to students.